# Change `hint text` length of textfield before gets truncated

Tags: flutter

How to change `hint text` length, of `textfield` widget?. The hint text is truncated with `...` for an example, `Write your text here by cli...`. But I need it to show the full length.

```
TextField(
            minLines: null,
            maxLines: null,
            maxLength: 100,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: InputBorder.none,
    hintText: 'Write your text here by clicking here on this loonnggggg text'
  ),
),
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `hintMaxLines`. like `hintMaxLines: 2`

```
TextField(
      minLines: null,
      maxLines: null,
      maxLength: 100,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: InputBorder.none,
        hintText: 'Write your text here by clicking here on this loonnggggg text',
        hintMaxLines: 2,
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below code hope its help to you. Used `hintMaxLines` property for that

Refer `hintMaxLines` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/hintMaxLines.html)

Refer `InputDecoration` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration-class.html)

```
TextField(
          minLines: null,
          maxLines: null,
          maxLength: 100,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            hintText:
                'Write your text here by clicking here on this loonnggggg textWrite your text here by clicking here on this loonnggggg text',
            hintMaxLines: 3,
          ),
        ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

define the `hintMaxLines` after the hintText.
example :
`hintText` : 'this is hintText', `hintMaxLines`: 3